# How to reference <a> within <li> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the `HREF`s in a list with new URLs.

I have something like this:

```
<ul id="sidebarItems">
   <li><a href="/PartBasicInfo/XX">Part Basic Info</a></li>
   <li><a href="/SupplierContracts/XX">Supplier Contracts</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying this (I know there are lots of ways to do it), but not having any luck. Any ideas?

```
function SetUrlParams() {
        $("#sidebarItems > li > a").each(function (idx, a) {
            a.attr("href", "MyURLOfChoice");
        });
```

Comment: Also, why am I not seeing the formatting toolbar when I make my posts? Would like to mark code blocks.

Comment: Re: your comment, no idea. It works just fine for me. Ask on Meta.

Comment: Re the disappearing formatting toolbar, I don't think it has anything to do with you particularly. That happens to me once in a great while. Refreshing the page can fix it.

Comment: I've verified that the loop is executing and that "this.href" is, in fact, the old hyperlink. However, when the loop is done executing and I hover over the menu items, they still have their old values.

Comment: @birdus Use `$(this).attr('href', "foo")` if you want to change the HTML element, not just the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter is the DOM element, not the jQuery element, wrap `a` with `$(a)`

```
function SetUrlParams() {
    $("#sidebarItems > li > a").each(function(idx, a) {
        $(a).attr("href", "MyURLOfChoice");
    });
}​
```

Or  leave jQuery for this simple task:

```
function SetUrlParams() {
    $("#sidebarItems > li > a").each(function(idx, a) {
        a.href = "MyURLOfChoice";
    });
}​
```

Note that you can access the DOM element with `this` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this where `this` refers to each of the anchor element in the matched set.

```
 function SetUrlParams() {
    $("#sidebarItems > li > a").each(function(){
       this.href = "MyURLOfChoice";
    });
 }
```

Note that in your code `a` refers to the dom element so you should convert it to jQuery object before calling any jQuery method if you want to keep your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#sidebaritems > li > a').each( function(){
    this.href = newURL;
});
```

Comment: Note that you changed his selector.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in the function passed to `each` will be the DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need to use `$(a)`, or just `$(this)` would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

i tested this and it is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GbyJU/)

```
$("#sidebarItems > li > a").each(function (idx, a) {
        $(a).attr("href", "MyURLOfChoice");
    });
```

it appears that a parameter is a HtmlElement, not wrapped by jquery